# phpseclib - Parse mysql query to array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ssh, phpseclib

I do a mysql select query over ssh2 with phpseclib.

I get my result back. If I add nl2br(), it's kind of readable (every row is on a seperate line). But I still can't access the columns of the rows.

How can I properly parse the output of a phpseclib ssh2 mysql query into a recursive array?

This is how I do my query:
$output = $ssh->exec('mysql -uMyUser -pMyPassword MyTable -e "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT"');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `str_replace("\t", ',', $output)` would probably work.

Here's how you'd get it into an associative array (not what you asked but it could prove useful to helping you understanding how the output is formatted):

```
$output = $ssh->exec('mysql -uMyUser -pMyPassword MyTable -e "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT"');
$output = explode("\n", $output);
$colNames = explode("\t", $output[0]);
$colValues = explode("\t", $output[1]);

$cols = array_combine($colNames, $colValues);
```